# Excel on Mac: How to access DevTools for Dialog content?

Tags: excel, macos, office-js, office-addins

I am developing an Office-Addin for Excel, and I am developing on a Mac.  I have followed the instructions at the following link in order to enable the Safari Web Inspector:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/testing/debug-office-add-ins-on-ipad-and-mac

This works and I can right-click, and "Inspect Element" in my Taskpane, and everything works as expected.

However: when I open a dialog in Excel, I loose the ability to accomplish this.  I can right-click in my dialog, and click "Inspect Element", but no inspector is opened.  Is there a way to accomplish what I am wanting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Make the window smaller before you right click on inspect, this may force the debugger to pop-out.

Answer (score 0):

The only time that happened to me had to do something with the npm package that I installed and a method call that I used there but after commenting package import and a method call I got the inspector back.